# rails create method with return a bool value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, import, return-value

I'm  a Ruby on Rails's beginner and so sorry for this stupid question but I've searched for it all day and still stuck at it :(

I've a model method to import file excel from computer to web with has 1st row contains table column, and other next rows have collection of record to save to database. I've tried to return true if it can save all records to db, else is false, like this:

**Model**

```
 def self.import(file)
   spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)    //another method to read file
   header = spreadsheet.row(1)
   (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
     row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
     item= find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
     item.attributes = row.to_hash.slice(*accessible_attributes)
     if item.invalid?{
     return false;
     break
   }
    else item.save end
   end
 end
```

And call it in **Controller** :

```
 def save
   if (Item.import(params[:file]))
     redirect_to import_items_path, notice: t("success")
   else redirect_to import_items_path, notice: t("fails")
   end
 end
```

But it didn't return true/false ( with always set "success" to flash.notice) when I imported

I've have call it to a variable like this

```
@test = Item.import(params[:file])
```

and sent it to flash.notice and found out that method always return a string like this

> "2..xx" (with xx is a number of rows in file)

Did i make somethings weird to call ??? Plz help me ... thks 1st for anykind of answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `import` method  does not return `true` if no invalid `items` are encountered.

To fix this, replace:

```
     if item.invalid?{
     return false;
     break
   }
    else taisan.save end
   end
 end
```

With:

```
    return false if item.invalid?
    taisan.save
  end
  true
end
```

Which will return `false` immediately an invalid `item` is encountered or `true` otherwise.

As an aside, you could keep your `save` function [dry](/questions/tagged/dry) like this:

```
def save
  message = if Item.import(params[:file])
              "success"
            else
              "failure"
            end

  redirect_to import_items_path, notice: t(message)
end
```

Comment: yes, it's work !!! I edit a bit 'cause there's some mistake i made when create question, my bad xD.
Btw, your answer help me realize that my method is weird at all ( maybe 'because of i just moved from C# to Ruby) many thanks John .

Comment: about a `notice:` Because i use another language in my web so I'm going to use locales like 't("flash.import_msg")` and `t("flash.import_error")`, so I wrote like this. Is it right ?